# How can I get a range from a textfile in Android Studio?

Tags: java, string, android-studio

My `.txt` file looks like this:

```
long:4.6789,lat:6.7890,time:08:22
```

But I don't know how to get that as strings, like so:

```
String long = 4.6789
String lat = 6.7890
String time = 08:22
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more..

Comment: String long =String.ValueOf(4.6789);

Comment: Ok what you can do is you can read a file and write long:4.6789 to String long=4.6789 to another file as an output or convert it in the same place

Comment: Read the text file and get the whole line to a String. Then use split() method to split it from ',' and assign it to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to get the desired values as `String`:

```
// fill in the path to file here
String yourFileName = "...";
try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(yourFileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
    for (String line : lines) {
        String longValue = line.split(",")[0].split("long:")[1];
        String latValue = line.split(",")[1].split("lat:")[1];
        String timeValue = line.split(",")[2].split("time:")[1];
        System.out.println(longValue + " - " + latValue + " - " + timeValue);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The response for your example is:

```
4.6789 - 6.7890 - 08:22
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .txt file placed in res/raw then for get String from  file you need to use this below line:

```
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
String data=convertIOStreamToString(is);

  String longValue = data.split(",")[0].split("long:")[1];
        String latValue = data.split(",")[1].split("lat:")[1];
        String timeValue = data.split(",")[2].split("time:")[1];
```

Convert InputStream to String method:

```
private String convertIOStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
{
int ch;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((ch = inputStream.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char)ch);
reset();
return sb.toString();
}
```